# Order records added in last 3 days first (exclude certain product type), then order by other columns

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
SELECT
    prod.*,
    details.specification,
    details.warrantyinfo
FROM
    Products prod 
INNER JOIN  ProductDetails  details 
    ON details.product_id = prod.id 
WHERE 
    prod.is_approved = '1' 
    AND prod.is_active = '1'
    AND prod.is_deleted = '0' 
    ORDER BY  
        prod.created_at > '2017-08-14' DESC,  
        IF(prod.created_at > '2017-08-14', prod.created_at, FIELD(prod.listing_type,2,3,4,5,6))  DESC,  
        prod.is_featured DESC, prod.updated_at DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

What this query actually does is -

1. sort products added in last three days first,
2. Then sort product according to `listing_type`
3. Then by `is_featured`, etc.

**Problem**

This works perfectly well, but in 1st sort condition I want to exclude product if `listing_type` is 2.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this

**SQLFIDDLE**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb584/1

Thanks

Comment: can you please create an SQL fiddle with some data, it will take a 5 minutes, here is a link http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @droidnation Please check my updated post above

Comment: So you want to remove from results every product have a `listing_type=2` ? Wait a second

Comment: Or you don't want to sort any product with `listing_type=2` and put it at the end of the result array ?

Comment: @droidnation, the result is okay, but records with `listing_type = 2` should come last. i.e matching `FIELD(prod.listing_type,2,3,4,5,6)` sort condition

Comment: So you need to sort them as the current query does but only those who have `listing_type=2` should come last

Comment: @droidnation, yes, `listing_type >2` should follow the 1st sort condition, then rest should follow the rest condtion

Comment: Use `ORDER BY case when...`

Comment: @droidnation, I can't use `CASE` here because I am using Phalcon php framework and its wrapper doesn't support `CASE`, but i can use `IF` though. But can't think of how to, can  you help me with this?

Comment: To exclude `listing_type=2` from your first sort condition, you just have to exclude `listing_type=2` from your first sort condition: `order by prod.created_at > '2017-08-14' AND listing_type!=2 DESC,  ... ` (assuming it is never `null`). You can actually add it to your second condition and remove the first one, as it does something similar, just differs in where the `listing_type=2` rows should go (which is unclear): `date > '2017-08-14'` for `type !=2`, then `date > '2017-08-14'` for `type=2` (or not!?), then all `date <= '2017-08-14'`, ordered by type (first type 6, then 5,4,3,2,others)?

Comment: @Solarflare That was very simple.  `order by prod.created_at > '2017-08-14' AND listing_type!=2 ` worked flawlessly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble into similar issue in future,

Actually modified the query to this. Thanks @Solarflare

```
SELECT
    prod.*,
    details.specification,
    details.warrantyinfo
FROM
    Products prod 
INNER JOIN  ProductDetails  details 
    ON details.product_id = prod.id 
WHERE 
    prod.is_approved = '1' 
    AND prod.is_active = '1'
    AND prod.is_deleted = '0' 
    ORDER BY  
        prod.created_at > '2017-08-14' AND prod.`listing_type`>2  DESC,  
        IF(prod.created_at > '2017-08-14' AND prod.`listing_type`>2, prod.created_at, FIELD(prod.listing_type,2,3,4,5,6))  DESC,  
        prod.is_featured DESC
```

And this worked flawlessly.